# HAProxy 1.7 not resolving docker 1.13.1 container

Tags: haproxy, docker

`docker ps -a`:

```
de09facf7c91        x/x:x   "/usr/bin/supervisord"   51 minutes ago      Up 24 minutes       8080/tcp                                                                           development-karl
226a1b80a233        x/x:x                                      "/usr/bin/supervisord"   2 hours ago         Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:80-84->80-84/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:1988->1988/tcp, 5672/tcp   haproxy
```

Started the container with this: `docker run --name development-karl -h development-karl -d x/x:x`

part of my `haproxy.cfg`:

```
backend karl_dev_backend
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    server      karl_dev development-karl cookie development-karl weight 1 maxconn 1024 check
```

Get the error in the haproxy logs:

```
[ALERT] 059/222244 (683) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:67] : 'server karl_dev' : could not resolve address 'development-karl'.
[ALERT] 059/222244 (683) : Failed to initialize server(s) addr.
```

I don't know why it's not resolving?

### EDIT, added answer info:

`https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#the-default-bridge-network-in-detail`:

> Docker does not support automatic service discovery on the default
>   bridge network. If you want to communicate with container names in
>   this default bridge network, you must connect the containers via the
>   legacy docker run --link option.

Legacy is pre version 1.10.

Legacy: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/

More info on legacy linking: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/work-with-networks/#linking-containers-without-using-user-defined-networks

Comment: Did you start the haproxy container with `--link development-karl`?

Comment: @jordanm I did not! I have the same setup on a separate server so I'm slightly confused :/ I suspect it has to do with docker and that it's "hiding" the containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe DNS discovery is enabled on the default docker bridge network. To connect multiple containers together with DNS discovery, create a network and attach both containers to that network:

```
docker network create proxy
docker network connect proxy haproxy
docker network connect proxy development-karl
```

You can also pass `--net proxy` to the `docker run` command instead of doing the `docker network connect` after the fact.

Comment: I see! I did a `docker network inspect bridge` however and they are all listed there?

Comment: Reread the first line of the answer please.

Comment: Ah, I misread it. You are correct! I've updated your answer with the relevant links.